# Разбить "класс-бог"

Tags: c#, wcf

В моём проекте есть сервис WCF, есть интерфейс описывающий ServiceContract (IMainHost), и есть класс на основе этого интерфейса (MainHost). И всё отлично работает. Смущает только одно - класс такого размера что студия тормозит когда я его редактирую. Создавать ещё один сервис так себе вариант. Я его конечно могу сделать partial, но вдруг есть какие то другие варианты?

Comment: Такой большой, что аж _Студия тормозит_? Это должно быть тысяч 20 строк?

Comment: @VladD, нет это 3к строк, но при вводе кода IntelliSense грузит проц на 100% что создаёт ощутимую задержку, ну и может ещё решарпер подтупливает

Comment: "...3к строк..." :) похоже, кто-то забыл про принцип `Single Responsibility`

Comment: @Bulson, этот принцип как раз не даёт мне покоя, я множество раз анализировал этот класс на единственную ответственность, и приходил к выводу что ответственность у его одна, это класс взаимодействия чата с сервером. Кроме того выделение разных областей ответственности внутри функционала чата, приводит к тому что надо создавать несколько сервисов, что тянет за собой открытие нескольких портов и тд...

Comment: В данный момент вы видите свой класс как монолитную стену, ваша задача увидеть эту стену таким образом, чтобы стали видны кирпичи, из которых она сложена.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Делегирование (англ. Delegation) — основной шаблон проектирования, в котором объект внешне выражает некоторое поведение, но в реальности передаёт ответственность за выполнение этого поведения связанному объекту.

Часть внутренней реализации MainHost вынести по смыслу в отдельные классы и использовать их внутри MainHost.

Comment: Хороший вариант, наверное стоит ещё подумать и что то вынести в отдельные классы, правда у меня множество разных действий уже и так вынесено в отдельные классы, например запросы к БД, колбеки, различные хелперы, не приведёт ли всё это к созданию "спагетти кода"?

Comment: Это уже зависит от вашей реализации.

Comment: @ИванК Начните писать unit-тесты на свой “класс-бог”. Часть методов придется сделать для этого публичными. Через это к вам придет понимание каким образом можно разбить на ассоциированные классы. Потом будет след. этап - создание таких классов и переписывание уже под них тестов. Работая через тесты можно добиться поставленной цели и быть уверенным в результате.

Comment: @Bulson, это реализация интерфейса - там все методы публичные, скорее всего.

Comment: @Qwertiy не пугайте меня так :) Вы уж совсем представляете страшную ситуацию - класс в котором методы занимают от 200 и более строк кода. Все же я надеюсь на лучшее, т.е. методы реализующие интерфейс вызывают приватные методы, имеющие разумный функционал и размер.

Comment: @Bulson, [почему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/733437/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b3/733451?noredirect=1#comment1130668_733451)?

Comment: @Qwertiy я не сразу понял ваш вопрос. Не, ну получилось и слава богу. Я тогда так сказанул, потому что речь шла об огромном классе реализующем интерфейс, а этот интерфейс в теории ну никак не может быть больше 10-15 методов.

Comment: @Bulson, это же wcf. Один метод интерфейса - один запрос. Для каждой сущности запросов минимум 5 (get all, get, create, update, delete), а скорее больше - всякие поиски. Если все сущности идут через один сервис (а это удобно, т. к. получается один iis-сайт, дибо один windwos-сервис), то методов в нём будет полно. Вон у него 570 срок с однострочными методами получилось - думаю, метовов не меньше сотни или двух.

Answer (score 3):

Методы wcf-сервиса должны представлять собой всего несколько строк:

```
[АтрибутДляКонтроляПравДоступа(какие, то, параметры)]
public Метод(Его аргументы)
{
  return КакойТоBll.Метод(аргументы);
}
```

Итого 6 строк (одна пустая) на метод. Остальное следует разложить по bll-классам.

Comment: Спасибо, за подсказки, думаю я так примерно и сделаю, жаль нельзя отметить 2 ответа как правильные

Comment: Мне и этот вариант кажется слишком сложным...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а поподробнее?

Comment: @Qwertiy `return КакойТоBll.Метод(аргументы);` - лишняя строчка

Comment: @Qwertiy да и `public Метод(Его аргументы)` - тоже

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а как тогда?

Comment: @Qwertiy тут писать долго. Вот вам код если сможете разобраться что он делает: https://github.com/mayorovp/mics_files/blob/master/AutofacServiceHost.cs

Comment: @Qwertiy подробности я уже обещал тут рассказать в выходные

Comment: @PavelMayorov, самому разруливать соответствия методов вместо стандартных атрибутов на интерфейсе? Не согласен, что это правильный подход. И wsdl по этому чуду само не построится.

Comment: @Qwertiy зачем вместо? Я что, предложил запретить интерфейсы? :-)

Comment: @Qwertiy и не вижу причин почему wsdl не построится. У меня вот строился же...

Comment: Переписал так как посоветовал @Qwertiy получилось 570 строк, вроде тормоза исчезли. Правда у меня по 1 строке на метод, вот как то так: ```public async Task<ICollection<CommonUser>> GetOnlineUsersAsync() => await this.general_info_bll.GetOnlineUsersAsync();```

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ты, вроде, ответить что-то интересное собирался?